# Does this cause leak of NSString?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I am a C programmer, but is pretty new to Objective-C. I've seen NSString-related code like this several times:

```
NSAppleScript* script = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource: @"<some script code>"];
...
[script release];
```

The above code explicitly releases the NSAppleScript object, but doesn't seem to release the NSString object anywhere.

I wondered if the `[script release]` automatically does the job of implicit release of the NSString object, so I changed the above code to the following:

```
NSString* scriptText = @"<some script code>";
NSAppleScript* script = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource: scriptText];
...
[script release];
//If [script release] has implicitly released scriptText,
//this would cause a repeated release.
[scriptText release];
```

But the above code turned out running also well. Does it mean that `[script release]` doesn't automatically release the NSObject object? In other words, does the code in the first section leak release of the NSString?

Comment: You should enable ARC (automatic reference counting) which exists for many years and manages retain/release on your behalf. Apart from that string literals are treated as constants and are not affected by reference counting.

Comment: If you can transition to ARC, that will simplify your life greatly. If you are stuck with manual reference counting, though, Xcode’s “static analyzer” (shift+command+B or “Analyze” on Xcode’s “Product” menu) is remarkably good at analyzing your code looking for manual reference counting issues. Make sure you get a clean bill of health from the static analyzer.

Comment: You have a lot of great answers and that you should listen to. I just want to point out that in normal C you'd ```alloc``` and ```free``` and take a lot of care to ensure you balance it to prevent leaks. When you turn on ARC this all happens automatically and you are not concerned about memory leaks. Sure, sometimes for special cases you can run into trouble, but ARC mostly gets it right and if you use Objective-C (with ARC) correctly then you need not worry about a pointer's release. So don't try to replace C's ```free``` with ```release```, just turn on ARC and start having fun.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful suggestions on ARC, I will turn it on. Might also be helpful to understand the underlyin mechanism and implicit rules hidden by ARC anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very short answer: no. You shouldn't release `scriptText`. (In fact, you must not.)

In ObjC manual reference counting, you need to follow the rules, which are based on method names. If you call a method whose name begins with `alloc` or `new` or includes `copy`, then you are responsible for calling `release` or `autorelease` on the object that is returned to you. Also, if you call `retain` on an object, you are responsible to call `release` or `autorelease`.

Following the rules, you called `+[NSAppleScript alloc]`, so you are responsible for calling `release` on the object returned to you. You did not call a retaining method to get `scriptText`; you used an NSString literal (`@"..."`). So you must not call `release` on it. It doesn't leak. (If it did, it would indicate a bug in Apple's code.)

The way this actually works is that NSString literals are stored directly in the binary, just like in C. There is no need to manage them, since they do not directly use memory. But this has nothing to do with your obligations under manual reference counting. You shouldn't think "this is a string literal so I shouldn't call `release` on it." That's not true at all. You should call `release` when the rules tell you to call `release`. It is completely correct to call `retain` on a value that happens to be a literal, and later call `release` on it. (This happens all the time. You generally don't know whether the NSString you're working with is a literal or not.)

It happens to be true that calling `retain` or `release` on NSString literals does nothing. They just ignore the call. Very short NSString objects don't even exist in memory. If they're short enough, the data is stored directly in the pointer (called a "tagged pointer"). Again, this is just an implementation detail. Your job is to follow the rules, not try to second-guess the system.

(The reason that your incorrect code with the extra `release` "works" is because literal NSStrings ignore memory management calls. The code is still incorrect. There's also no promise that over-releasing an object will cause a crash in any case, and it is very, very common when it does crash for it to occur at a random point, far away from the mistake. It's very common for objects to have pending `autorelease` calls on them, so you get a crash when the pool drains, with no hint where your bug is.)

And of course you should turn on ARC and let it handle it for you. It does a very good job. But it's helpful to understand the rules anyway. ARC uses the same name-based rules to figure out where to put retains and releases. That's how it can interoperate seamlessly with manual memory management.

Comment: I love this answer

Comment: Thank you for your great answer. The detailed answer explains the conception and mechanism about NSString and NSString literals very comprehensively.